# How to save the newly entered item into combobox itemssource?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I am trying to add new item in to Combobox .For ex : if the ComboBox itemssource having "one","two",and "three ". I am able to type by setting IsEditable property to  true . New item "Four" which is need to save in combobox . Please share regarding this .

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:OrderInfoRepositiory x:Key="ordercollection"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

`<ComboBox x:Name="combo" IsEditable="True" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems,Source={StaticResource ordercollection}}" Height="50" Width="150"/>`

code behind :

```
void combo_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var combo=(sender as ComboBox);
        (combo.DataContext as OrderInfoRepositiory).ComboItems.Add(combo.Text);
    }


private ObservableCollection<string> comboItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> ComboItems
    {
        get { return comboItems; }
        set 
        { 
            comboItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ComboItems");
        }
    }

public OrderInfoRepositiory()
    {
        orderCollection = new ObservableCollection<OrderInfo>();
        OrderInfoCollection = GenerateOrders();
        foreach (OrderInfo o in orderCollection)
        {
            comboItems.Add(o.Country);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it work when you restart the Application? is there a new entry then?

Comment: And where is these comboItems defined?

Comment: ComboItems defined in ViewModel

Comment: I'm guessing orderCollection is a CollectionViewSource defined in XAML. Can we see that? Can we see the code for ComboItems property?

Comment: Please find the edited code snippet

Answer (score 1):

**PreviewKeyDown**

Your ComboBox is not bound to the `EventHandler` `comboBox_PreviewKeyDown`.

Are you really want to use PreviewKeyDown?
With `PreviewKeyDown` `comboBox.Text` still has the Text before excluding your pressed key. Use KeyDown instead.

Each Keypress will add the new and the old typed letters. 
Typing "Hello World" will end in H, He, Hel, Hell, etc.
Check for `Key.Return` to add the Item on completion or use a button. Then you can still use the PreviewKeyDown Event.

```
void combo_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        var combo = (sender as ComboBox);
        (combo.DataContext as OrderInfoRepository).ComboItems.Add(combo.Text);
    }
}
```

**DataContext**

You are casting `DataContext` to `OrderInfoRepositiory` but there is no assignment in your code.

Add to your `ComboBox`:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ordercollection}}"
```

Then you can change your `ItemsSource`:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}"
```

I prefer setting `OrderInfoRepositiory` in my underlying ViewModel, then you do not need the StaticResource and just bind to the property.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="combo" IsEditable="True" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ordercollection}}" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboItems}" Height="50" Width="150" KeyDown="combo_PreviewKeyDown"/>
```